# Better way for the special concatenation of two strings

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, string

I want to concatenate two strings in such a way, that after the first character of the first string, the first character of second string comes, and then the second character of first string comes and then the second character of the second string comes and so on.  Best explained by some example cases:

```
    s1="Mark";
    s2="Zukerberg";  //Output=> MZaurkkerberg
```

if:

```
    s1="Zukerberg";
    s2="Mark"        //Output=> ZMuakrekrberg
```

if:

```
    s1="Zukerberg";
    s2="Zukerberg";  //Output=> ZZuukkeerrbbeerrgg
```

I've written the following code which gives the expected output but its seems to be a lot of code. Is there any more efficient way for doing this?

```
public void SpecialConcat(string s1, string s2)
        {
            string[] concatArray = new string[s1.Length + s2.Length];
            int k = 0;
            string final = string.Empty;
            string superFinal = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        concatArray[k] = s1[i].ToString() + s2[j].ToString();
                        final = string.Join("", concatArray);
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }
            if (s1.Length > s2.Length)
            {
                string subOne = s1.Remove(0, s2.Length);
                superFinal = final + subOne;
            }
            else if (s2.Length > s1.Length)
            {
                string subTwo = s2.Remove(0, s1.Length);
                superFinal = final + subTwo;
            }
            else
            {
                superFinal = final;
            }
            Response.Write(superFinal);
        }
    }
```

I have written the same logic in Javascript also, which works fine but again a lot of code.

Comment: @Jonesy Nothing just for fun and some practice. :)

Comment: Use IEnumerable<T>.Zip. You'll need ta add the trailing chars yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var s1 = "Mark";
var s2 = "Zukerberg";
var common = string.Concat(s1.Zip(s2, (a, b) => new[]{a, b}).SelectMany(c => c));
var shortestLength = Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length);
var result = 
     common + s1.Substring(shortestLength) + s2.Substring(shortestLength);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm going to try this out. :)

Comment: damn, i really need to work on my linq skills, this is pretty clever

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, when working with strings, you are also working with arrays, so it will be easier.  Also `+` will concatenate for you.  Replace string indexing with `charAt` if you want IE7- support.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z6XLh/1

```
var s1 = "Mark";
var s2 = "ZuckerFace";
var out ='';

var l = s1.length > s2.length ? s1.length : s2.length
for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if(s1[i]) {
        out += s1[i];
    }
    if(s2[i]){
        out += s2[i];
    }
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: It does now, after your changes :-)

Comment: If it matters, old browsers (IE 7 and before, at least) don't support `String[index]` - you should use `String.charAt(index)` for better support

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try and response back. :)

Comment: It's all for the honor of papa smurf!

Answer (score 5):

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(s1.Length, s2.Length); i++)
{
    if (i < s1.Length)
        stringBuilder.Append(s1[i]);

    if (i < s2.Length)
        stringBuilder.Append(s2[i]);
}

string result = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: Nice use of stringbuilder.. although I do believe this has a lot of excessive `if` checking.... ie `s1 = "a", s2 = "bcderfgasdfaersasadfas"`

Comment: It would be slightly better to say `new StringBuilder(s1.Length + s2.Length)`, otherwise the underlying array might have to be copied over to a longer array once in a while during execution.

Answer (score 3):

```
static string Join(string a, string b)
{
   string returnVal = "";
   int length = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      returnVal += "" + a[i] + b[i];

   if (a.Length > length)
      returnVal += a.Substring(length);
   else if(b.Length > length)
      returnVal += b.Substring(length);

   return returnVal;
}
```

Could possibly be improved through stringbuilder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this out. Yes I had also thought of StringBuilder but didn't apply yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of curiosity, here's an unreadable one-liner (which I have nevertheless split over multiple lines ;))

This uses the fact that padding a string to a certain length does nothing if the string is already at least that length. That means padding each string to the length of the other string will have the result of padding out with spaces the shorter one to the length of the longer one.

Then we use `.Zip()` to concatenate each of the pairs of characters into a string.

Then we call `string.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` to concatenate the zipped strings into a single string.

Finally, we remove the extra padding spaces we introduced earlier by using `string.Replace()`.

```
var result = string.Concat
(
    s1.PadRight(s2.Length)
    .Zip
    (
        s2.PadRight(s1.Length), 
        (a,b)=>string.Concat(a,b)
    )
).Replace(" ", null);
```

On one line [insert Coding Horror icon here]:

```
var result = string.Concat(s1.PadRight(s2.Length).Zip(s2.PadRight(s1.Length), (a,b)=>string.Concat(a,b))).Replace(" ", null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, it really helped. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Just off the top of my head, this is how I might do it.

```
        var s1Length = s1.Length;
        var s2Length = s2.Length;
        var count = 0;
        var o = "";
        while (s1Length + s2Length > 0) {
            if (s1Length > 0) {
                s1Length--;
                o += s1[count];
            }
            if (s2Length > 0) {
                s2Length--;
                o += s2[count];
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one-liner:

```
var s1 = "Mark";
var s2 = "Zukerberg";
var result = string.Join("", 
  Enumerable.Range(0, s1.Length).ToDictionary(x => x * 2, x => s1[x])
  .Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, s2.Length).ToDictionary(x => x * 2+1, x => s2[x]))
  .OrderBy(d => d.Key).Select(d => d.Value));
```

Basically, this converts both strings into dictionaries with keys that will get the resulting string to order itself correctly. The Enumerable range is used to associate an index with each letter in the string. When we store the dictionaries, it multiplies the index on s1 by 2, resulting in <0,M>,<2,a>,<4,r>,<6,k>, and multiplies s2 by 2 then adds 1, resulting in <1,Z>,<3,u>,<5,k>, etc.

Once we have these dictionaries, we combine them with the .Concat and sort them with the .OrderBy,which gives us <0,M>,<1,Z>,<2,a>,<3,u>,... Then we just dump them into the final string with the string.join at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain a bit, I'm not that expert in C#. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the *second shortest solution I could come up with:

```
    public string zip(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1+s2))
            ? (s1[0] + "" + s2[0] + zip(s1.Substring(1) + " ", s2.Substring(1) + " ")).Replace(" ", null)
            : "";
    }

    var result =  zip("mark","zukerberg");
```

Whoops! My original shortest was the same as mark's above...so, second shortest i could come up with! I had hoped I could really trim it down with the recursion, but not so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sWordOne = "mark";// ABCDEF
var sWordTwo = "zukerberg";// 123
var result  = (sWordOne.Length > sWordTwo.Length) ? zip(sWordOne, sWordTwo) : zip(sWordTwo, sWordOne);
//result = "zmuakrekrberg"


 static string zip(string sBiggerWord, string sSmallerWord)
{
    if (sBiggerWord.Length < sSmallerWord.Length) return string.Empty;// Invalid 
    if (sSmallerWord.Length == 0) sSmallerWord = " ";
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(sBiggerWord) ? string.Empty : (sBiggerWord[0] + "" + sSmallerWord[0] + zip(sBiggerWord.Substring(1),sSmallerWord.Substring(1))).Replace(" ","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative without Linq witchcraft:

```
string Merge(string one, string two)
{
    var buffer = new char[one.Length + two.Length];
    var length = Math.Max(one.Length, two.Length);
    var index = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i ++)
    {
        if (i < one.Length) buffer[index++] = one[i];
        if (i < two.Length) buffer[index++] = two[i];
    }

    return new string(buffer);
}
```